# disable Magento MSI Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, msi, magento2.4.4

I'm trying to disable Msi module on Magento 2.4.4 using the following command:

> php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory
> Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi
> Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales
> Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
> Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
> Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
> Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
> Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport
> Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
> Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
> Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
> Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations
> Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache
> Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi
> Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping
> Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection
> Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
> Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
> Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock
> Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
> Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
> Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl
> Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport
> Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension
> Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi
> Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi
> Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi
> Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist

I took it From this Post https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-magento-msi/
for magento 2.4.2 it was working but now after I upgraded to 2.4.4 I'm getting module's dependency errors :

> Unable to change status of modules because of the following
> constraints: Cannot disable Magento_Inventory because modules depend
> on it:
>
> Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct:
> Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct->Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_Inventory
> Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct:
> Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct->Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_Inventory
> Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl:
> Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl->Magento_InventoryCatalog->Magento_Inventory
> Cannot disable Magento_InventoryApi because modules depend on it:

Does anyone tried to disable MSI on magneot 2.4.4?
Thank you,

Comment: You just need to add missed (new) extension to your command `Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct  Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just completely removing the modules using composer.

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory
```

The advantage of doing it this way is the modules don't even get installed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this better approach to disable the MSI modules

Answer (score 2):

Disable MSI in Magento 2.4.4 or 2.4.5 use below command

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct  Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl
```

Then run:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:f
```