# Disabling MSI - any side effects?

Tags: msi, magento2.4.5

I need to disable MSI as source of truth is not Magento.
Before doing so (as per i.e. [disable Magento MSI Magento 2.4.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356945/disable-magento-msi-magento-2-4-4)) I would like to ask about possible side effects (shipments issues?) in Magento 2.4.5 and what may happen while upgrading Magento application...
What is a worst case scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is not using Multi warehouse system then MSI shall be disabled. This module is for stores that have multiple inventory points.
Most of the sites don't use and from optimization perspective as well any module not in use shall be disabled( also this will reduce your deployment time )

Comment: Thanks, I have disabled MSI and so far no issues related to it...

Comment: Nice to know that your problem is solved.